# No recibo el ID en el controlador desde ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo el siguiente código donde intento eliminar un registro con ajax para evitar la recarga de la ventana, pero no estoy recibiendo el ID en elcontrolador:

```
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

            <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2016-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2016" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2016" aria-selected="true">2016</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2017-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2017" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2017" aria-selected="false">2017</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2018-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2018" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2018" aria-selected="false">2018</a>
              <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-2019-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2019" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2019" aria-selected="false">2019</a>
              <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-2020-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-2020" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-2020" aria-selected="false">2020</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="tab-content col-lg-10" id="v-pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2016" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2016-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2017" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2017-tab">


                <div id="main">
                  @foreach($photos as $photo)
                    @if($photo->year == '2017')
                    <div class="box">
                      <div class="pic">
                        <div class="item{{$photo->id}}">
                          <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset($photo->dir . $photo->filename . '.' .$photo->extension) }}" alt="">
                          <button class="delete delete-modal btn btn-danger" data-id="{{$photo->id}}" data-title="{{$photo->title}}">
                            <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2018" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2018-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade pl-5" id="v-pills-2019" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2019-tab">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active pl-5" id="v-pills-2020" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-2020-tab">

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>           
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Modal form to delete a form -->
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h5 class="text-center">Confirme que quiere eliminar la fotografía</h5>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id">ID:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_delete" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer col-lg-12">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-dismiss="modal">
            Sí
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
            No
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Delete');
        $('#id_delete').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        id = $('#id_delete').val();
    });
    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.delete', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'DELETE',
            url: 'photos/' + id,
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
                $('.col1').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).html(index+1);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    dd($id);
    $delete = Photo::find($id);

    $delete->delete();

    return response()->json($delete);
}
```

Comment: La ruta tiene un parametro: photos/{photo}, el dd($id) no me muestra nada.

Comment: undefined en la línea console.log(data.data);

Comment: Ok, en el script, prueba declarando la variable id fuera de las funciones, apenas empieza el script `var id = null;` y luego las funciones.

Comment: Igual, undefined en console.log(data.data);

Comment: Ahí si me devolvió el objeto con los datos

Comment: Ok, ¿entonces está llegando la id al controlador? Si es así, quita ese `return $id;` que era sólo para debug

Comment: Ahora me elimina el archivo pero no me actualiza, cuando actualizo manualmente veo que lo eliminó.

Comment: y me muestra este error: ReferenceError: toastr is not defined

Comment: Tendrá algo que ver que uso nav-pills?

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de porloscerros Ψ y Carlos Cordova se resolvió.

Cambié la siguiente línea `$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {` por `$(document).on('click', '.delete-modal', function() {` y eliminé en la clase del botón el delete.

Comment: Yo no puedo votar en mi propia respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo. tienes dos clases **delete**
en uno tienes el *data-id* y en el otro no.
cuando haces el  **"$(this).data('id')"** uno te retorna nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tu ruta sea como la siguiente:

```js
Route::delete('/photos/{photo}', 'YourController@delete')->name('photo.delete');
//->name() no es requerido.
```

Tu método debería estar así:

```js
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Photo $photo //Verifica la ruta de tu modelo
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Photo $photo)
{
  //Tu lógica
}
```

Otro error es que la clase `delete` está duplicada. Elimina la clase `delete` del elemento que no es `button`, eso te causa problemas también.

En tu AJAX deberías usar `.data()` para obtener el id de tu foto, que quede algo así:

```js
 var photo_id =$(this).data('id');
 $.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: 'photos/' + photo_id,
    data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) {
        toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
        $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
        $('.col1').each(function (index) {
            $(this).html(index+1);
        });
    },
    error: function error(data) {
  //Hacer algo en caso de error 
 }
});
```